# What are the basic statistics to describe tensor data distribution

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, high-dimensional, tensor

For numeric data, the basic/straightforward way to describe its distribution is to use some metrics like mean, min, max, std et al.

What about tensor data (vectors and high dimensional data)?
Of course, the mean, std still holds but it is a high dimensional data point. Is there any scalars that can help describe the data.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multivariate+statistic for indications of additional statistics (beyond multivariate moments).